# Vite: prevent inline Base64 svg in css

Tags: css, svg, vite

I have a normal Vite 5.0.4 setup without any svg loader plugins.
I want to include a background svg image in my css file like this:

```
background-image: url("@assets/file.svg?url");
```

If i build the project, the file include will automatically be transformed to an inline base64 string. The ?url parameter which should keep it as an url is ignored.

The only workaround to keep the url as a file, is to set the [assetsInlineLimit](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-assetsinlinelimit) to 0.

I have also tried to use the vite-svg-loader plugin. But the file still gets inlines to a base64 string.

Is there another way to solve this issue without setting assetsInlineLimit to 0?

Comment: What's wrong with setting assetsInlineLimit to 0? Isn't that exactly what it's for?

Comment: Then all SVGs will be an url to a file. I only want specific SVGs to be an file.

Comment: Also, using `assetsInlineLimit` would apply to other asset types as well which you might not want.